# How to subtract data frame column from another data frame column if condition is met?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, subtraction

I have two simple data frames containing both the columns "word" and "n" for how often a certain word occurred. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(word=c("beautiful","nice","like","good"),n=c(400,378,29,10))
df2 <- data.frame(word=c("beautiful","nice","like","good","wonderful","awesome","sad","happy"),n=c(6000,20,5,150,300,26,17,195))
```

Besides the words of `df1`, `df2` contains much more words so `df1` is only a small subset of `df2`.

I found the words, that are contained in both, `df1` and `df2`. Now I would like to subtract the word countings of `df1` from `df2` if the specific word is contained in `df2` , meaning I would like to do the following:

- Subtract word counting: `df2$n - df1$n`
- only IF `df1$word` is contained in `df2$word`

I hope that my problem is clear.

I already found all the words from df1 that are also contained in df2

```
df1 %>% filter(df1$word %in% df2$word)
```

However, I am struggling with the subtracting command based on the condition that the words in df1 must be also in `df2` and then only subtract `df2$n - df1$n`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your example does not match your problem. There are not words in `df1` contained in `df2`

Comment: yes i recognized that sorry for that now i changed it

Answer (score 4):

Using `merge`:

```
> df.tmp <- merge(df1, df2, by="word", all=TRUE)
> df.tmp$result <- df.tmp$n.y - df.tmp$n.x
> df.tmp
       word n.x  n.y result
1 beautiful 400 6000   5600
2      good  10  150    140
3      like  29    5    -24
4      nice 378   20   -358
5   awesome  NA   26     NA
6     happy  NA  195     NA
7       sad  NA   17     NA
8 wonderful  NA  300     NA
```

If you only want matched words

```
> df.tmp <- merge(df1, df2, by="word")
> df.tmp$result <- df.tmp$n.y - df.tmp$n.x
> df.tmp
       word n.x  n.y result
1 beautiful 400 6000   5600
2      good  10  150    140
3      like  29    5    -24
4      nice 378   20   -358
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = 'word') %>% 
  mutate(diff = n.y - n.x) %>% 
  select(word, diff)
```

Gives

```
       word diff
1 beautiful 5600
2      nice -358
3      like  -24
4      good  140
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked really well

Comment: Is there also a possibility to receive a data frame of all words instead of only the matched words?

Comment: @Lucinho91 Yes, change `inner_join` to `left_join`

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work for me:/ It still only gives me the matched words instead of all

Comment: Oh, I thought you mean all words in df1. To show all words in df2, use `right_join`. Or for all words in both `df1` and `df2`, use `full_join`

Comment: Mh somehow this adds entries for me, my df2 contains 1390 entries and  my df1 415. After right joining the new df contains 1511 entries. that is strange. It should contain 1390 entries as well though so something is not working properly

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution using a for loop and the `%in%` operator.

```
df2$diff <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  if (df2$word[i] %in%  df1$word[i]) {
    df2$diff[i] <- df2$n[i] - df1$n[i]
  }
}
df2
```

Output:

```
> df2
       word    n diff
1 beautiful 6000 5600
2      nice   20 -358
3      like    5  -24
4      good  150  140
5 wonderful  300   NA
6   awesome   26   NA
7       sad   17   NA
8     happy  195   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized base solution where Boolean multiplication is used to replace an if-then construct used in the for-lop from @Rob:

```
 df2$n.adjusted <- df2$n - (df2$word %in% df1$word)* # zero if no match
                                 df1$n[ match(df1$word, df2$word) ] # gets order correct
> df2
       word    n n.adjusted
1 beautiful 6000       5600
2      nice   20       -358
3      like    5        -24
4      good  150        140
5 wonderful  300        300
6   awesome   26         26
7       sad   17         17
8     happy  195        195
```

Here's the example I used to test where the order of the df1 words was not  the same as the order in df2 and the lengths were not an even multiple:

```
> df1 <-data.frame(word=c("nice","beautiful","like","good"),n=c(378,400,29,10))
> df2 <- data.frame(word=c("beautiful","nice","like","good","wonderful","awesome","sad"),n=c(6000,20,5,150,300,26,17))
> 
>  df1
       word   n
1      nice 378
2 beautiful 400
3      like  29
4      good  10
>  df2
       word    n
1 beautiful 6000
2      nice   20
3      like    5
4      good  150
5 wonderful  300
6   awesome   26
7       sad   17
> df2$n.adjusted <- df2$n - (df2$word %in% df1$word)*df1$n[match(df1$word, df2$word)]
Warning message:
In (df2$word %in% df1$word) * df1$n[match(df1$word, df2$word)] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> df2
       word    n n.adjusted
1 beautiful 6000       5600
2      nice   20       -358
3      like    5        -24
4      good  150        140
5 wonderful  300        300
6   awesome   26         26
7       sad   17         17
```

Comment: I'm not totally happy with this solution. It throws a warning (although still a correct result) when the number of non-matched words is not equal to the number of matched words.